# Haskell function composition (forward pipe) - why does this work?

Tags: haskell

In the below code, `fibseq` represents a sequence of numbers from the Fibonacci sequence.
(from code to solve Project Euler #2)

I have defined an infix function `|>`:

```
(|>) x y = y x.
```

This lets me do the following (like a unix pipeline):

```
take 34 fibseq |> filter even |> filter (< 4000000) |> sum
```

My question is, why does this work?

I would have thought that  `take 34 fibseq |> filter even` ought to transform into `filter (take 34 fibseq) even`, which (I think) would lead to a type error.

Instead it seems to be transforming into `filter even (take 34 fibseq)` which works and is what I want, but I don't understand why it's working.

Comment: As a side note; You can also _define_ functions in infix notation: `x |> f = f x`

Answer (score 24):

Function application (like `filter even`) binds tighter than any operators, so your code is equivalent to:

```
(take 34 fibseq) |> (filter even) |> (filter (< 4000000)) |> sum
```

Comment: Isn't the default operator precedence `infixl 9`? Then what is `filter even`'s precedence?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I remember reading there two *things* in Haskell with 0 and 10 infix precedence, as the lowest and highest, "unattainable" infix options, respectively. Problem is, it turns out infix 0 is attainable, so maybe it's functions that were 10? But functions aren't even normally infix! Urgh, memory!

Answer (score 9):

This works because of operator precedence.  The function application operator, juxtaposition or  (the space), has the highest precedence, so `take 34 fibseq |> filter even` parses as `((take 34) fibseq) |> (filter even)`, which is equivalent to `(filter even) ((take 34) fibseq)`; since function application is left-associative, this is then equivalent to `filter even (take 34 fibseq)`.

In general, any binary operator can be given a precedence with a fixity declaration, such as

```
infixl 0 |> 
infixr 9 .
```

The `l` or `r` says whether the operation is left- or right-associative (that is, whether `a • b • c` groups as `(a • b) • c` or `a • (b • c)`); the number—an integer between 0 and 9—specifies the precedence level.  Higher numbers mean higher precedence (with application having an effective precedence of ∞); for instance, `*` and `/` have precedence 7, and `+` and `-` have precedence 6.  To check the precedence of an operator in ghci, just type `:info $` (or whichever operator) at the prompt.

And just as a note: your code will work, but it's not how I would typically write it.  If you're curious, in Haskell, I would write that code with the `$` operator, which just performs function application but is low precedence: `filter even $ take 34 fibseq`.  If I had more functions to apply, I would use the composition operator: `fun1 arg1 . fun2 . fun3 arg2 arg3 . filter even $ take 34 fibseq`.  It reads the other way, but it's what you typically find in Haskell.